# Encapsulating an exception in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, pip

How to decouple application from exceptions that creep in from used library dependencies?

```
[app] --uses--> [lib] --dependson--> [dependency]
                                           / /
  x- <-propagates--o <---throwsexception--' /
   \                                       /
    `-----needstohandle,soimports-----> --'
```

The problem is from real `pip` code:

1. module A (req/req_set.py) [depends on module B](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/36a0187476b06d531426df7688d814770e030443/pip/req/req_set.py#L10)
2. module B (download) [uses module C](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/36a0187476b06d531426df7688d814770e030443/pip/download.py#L26) (requests)
3. module [A imports](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/36a0187476b06d531426df7688d814770e030443/pip/req/req_set.py#L8) module C [to handle exception from C](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/36a0187476b06d531426df7688d814770e030443/pip/req/req_set.py#L363)

How to encapsulate exception in module B? To remove dependency on C from module A? How to make sure that the cause and details of original exception are not lost? In other words how can I reraise the exception with a different name?

The snippet below does what is needed, but it it Python 3 only:

```
 try:
     dependency_call()
 except DependencyError as exc:
     raise LibraryError from exc
```

**UPDATE**: I am looking for Python 2 compatible solution, the Python 3 added `raise ... from ...` that does the trick almost good.

**UPDATE 2**: The goal of encapsulating exception is to catch it in `[lib]` and re-throw a new one to `[app]` preserving the stack trace so that debug tools can still walk up the code (for human-only solution [the answer by Alex Thornton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26698747/239247) should be good).

Answer (score 4):

You can catch an arbitrary exception by referring to the `Exception` base class:

```
except Exception as exc:
    raise ApplicationError from exc
```

---

To get the `from` idiom to work in Python 2, you'll have to hack around with your custom exception:

```
class ApplicationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, cause, trace):
        self.cause = cause
        self.trace = trace
    def __str__(self):
        return '{origin}\nFrom {parent}'.format(origin=self.trace, 
                                                parent=self.cause)
```

And then raise it like this:

```
 except Exception, exc:
     raise ApplicationError(exc)
```

it will then print the `cause` when it is raised, which is also an attribute which you can access if you decide to catch the `ApplicationError` as well.

Comment: @techtonik The `from` is OK, you just need to define your own `ApplicationError` exception.

Comment: Looks like is it Python 3 stuff. For the Python 2 it gives SyntaxError - https://dpaste.de/SbtT

Comment: @techtonik: The way Mr. Thornton showcased his solution it looks like a "catch all", but i'm sure he just wanted to provide a solution as quickly as possible, and had confidence you would solve the "catch all" by re-raising the exception if it wasn't the specific one.

Comment: @DonQuestion, I was reading the answer too fast. The actual issue that I didn't know that this code actually compiles on Python 3. I updated the question and removed confusing comments.

Comment: That's cool. But it hides the trace of actual error. Python 3 shows a full log https://dpaste.de/ajjH (the code is here - https://dpaste.de/BW4T)

Comment: @techtonik You could fix that by modifying the class so it can inherit the `__traceback__` attribute of `exc`.

Comment: @techtonik Yet another update based on the suggested modification in the above comment.

Comment: I am worried that debuggers will not be able to ascend to the cause, because the internal chain is broken. How to inherit that `__traceback__` so that `ApplicationError` would just appear at the bottom of the stack and is printed by Python itself?

Comment: @techtonik To be honest, I don't know past what I have provided. You could always ask a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the question, so now it should be clear. There was no chance to make it good from the first try without these hints.

Answer (score 0):

If i do get you right, you would like to decouple more strongly and eliminate:

```
from pip._vendor import requests
```

and:

```
except requests.HTTPError as exc:
```

you could do that by introducing a last-resort fallback handler as the
last `except` of all except clauses like:

```
try:...
except A:
...   # here all your other exceptions
except Exception as exc:    # the fall-back handler
    if "HTTPError" in repr(exc):
       # do whatever you want to do with the (assumed) request.HTTPError
       # any other Exception with HTTPError in it's repr-string will be
       # caught here
```

The draw-back is, that it's still a tight coupling and a clear violation of the
"law of Demeter", because you would need to know some internals of an object which
isn't even in the object-composition. So in some sense it's even worse now.

Comment: Although it provides decoupling, I thing the code is worse than original and still doesn't provide encapsulation. In addition it removes the ability for static analysis or type checking. =)

Comment: I don't get your "encapsulation" argument. I don't see that as an issue in this case, because custom Exceptions are the complete opposite of "encapsulation" as they don't hide but add to complexity by exposing an additional public interface.

Comment: The chain consists of `[app]-->[lib]-->[dep]`. `[lib]` should encapsulate all `[dep]` exceptions to hide these additional public interfaces from it.

Comment: Exceptions are not meant to be hidden, but dealt with! Something in [lib] failed so hard that it compelled [dep] to throw an exception. Doesn't look rational to "hide" it! If [lib] can't handle it, what makes you think [app] could, without breaking the "law of Demeter"? btw: encapsulation is a horrible buzz-word and imho misleading for the issue at hand, especially the way you use it atm: hiding perceived misbehaviour at run time instead of exposing a clean interface to a type.

Comment: There are two ways to solve this dilemma imo. 1st: you could modify [lib] and wrap [dep]-excpetions in custom [lib]-exceptions. 2nd: you add an additional [exclib], which provides a "facade" for arbitrary exceptions.

Comment: I am for the 1st solution. As it appeared I need to port `raise ... from ...` to Python 2.

Comment: I'm still sceptical about both the issue and the solution(s), but i commend your enthusiasm. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking about how to make `pip` architecture more modular and this is a key issue.

Comment: I see. You are a pip-contributor. In that case i have a 3rd option: "inversion of control": allow the caller to hand an Exception-type to the callee. (Overoptimistic) And all your troubles will just vanish. No, seriously consider a "dependency injection". Thumbs up! BTW: 268 LOC for `prepare_files` omg, that's an insane overblown function. I didn't dare to peek further. My boss would kill me if i got side-tracked! ;-)

Comment: No, I am not pip contributor. =) Just studying code to see if the is any architecture that could make a `minipip` possible. Not sure that `[dep]` supports customizing raised exceptions, but that's an interesting stuff to think about. Thanks.